# animation flickering in listview while hide layout

Tags: android, listview, android-animation, onscrolllistener

There is a custom listview and in bottom there is a linearlayout. So while scrolling the list , actionbar and bottom layout should hide while scrolling the listview so we can see the list in full screen. I am using animation to hide/show the layout but there is a flickering when list reaches top. Below is the code for hide and show layout with actionbar.

```
           @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
          final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if(mViews.lists.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && (mViews.lists.getChildCount() == 0 || mViews.lists.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0)){
                actionBar.show();
             //   mViews.linear.startAnimation(animShow);
               // mViews.linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,2000,0 );

               animate.setDuration(100);

                animate.setFillBefore(true);


                animate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        mViews.linear.startAnimation(animation);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        mViews.linear.clearAnimation();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });

                mViews.linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            }else  {
                if (actionBar != null) {
                    actionBar.hide();
                  // mViews.linear.startAnimation(animHide);
                    //mViews.linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,0);
                   animate.setDuration(100);
                    animate.setFillAfter(true);
                    mViews.linear.startAnimation(animate);
                    animate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                            mViews.linear.startAnimation(animation);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            mViews.linear.clearAnimation();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                        }
                    });

                    mViews.linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


            }
        }
```

I have gone thru SO but i didnt find any solution which solves my problem.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/

you have to bind you view and then use

FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)yourView.getLayoutParams();

yourView.animate().translationY(mFabButton.getHeight()+fabBottomMargin).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();

see the tutorial and also find github code below